# What is the keyword for code generation of a return type in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I am writing code in Java in Intellij Idea, I use a function and I want to know how I can automatically generate the variable for it.

Let's say I have function `foo(int i)` that return a `String`, I want to write:

```
foo(2);
```

and then use it to generates something like:

```
String res = foo(2);
```

Is there anything like this in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called *Extract Variable*.

You can execute it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>